# How to integrate Google Analytics in the MainView (not inside) of a iOS Phonegap App?

Tags: ios, cordova, google-analytics

I hope the question is clear enough. Otherwise, I apologize.
I've made a Phonegap app that works fine in Android and iOS. It has a lot of html files inside, and I don't have any interest in tracking the use of them, but I do have it in knowing the difusion of the App, languages, devices, versions,... and all that stuff that can be provided only with the view that calls the cordova plugin.

On Android it's been very easy, following the standard instructions to include Google Analytics.

But I haven't found a way to do it on iOS. When following standard instructions (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/) I don't know what to do when arriving here:
[image]

Because what I find is:

[image]

When looking at CDVViewController, we see this:

[image]

I wonder where I'd have to place the libraries, if in the "app.xcodeproj" file or in the corresponding "CordovaLib.xcodeproj", and so on. I' ve tried, blindly, several posibilities, but nothing is working.

I must recognize that I know very little of iOS programming, just enough to make Phonegap apps, and then follow any kind of tutorials to improve them...

I've also tried other solutions, (without plugins...) but no way.

Is there any way to do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I got the solution!

What I did was:

1. Follow the steps 1 and 2 from the instructions in  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/

I don't know if it's relevant but in the step 1, I placed the SDK files in the Classes Folder of the App (where is AppDelegate.h ...)

In the step 2, remember to put at the beginning:

```
   #import "GAI.h"
```

1. En MainViewController.m put at the beginning

   ```
   #import "GAI.h"
   #import "GAIFields.h"
   #import "GAITracker.h"
   #import "GAIDictionaryBuilder.h"
   ```

Then comment out the lines:

```
/*

- (void) webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView*)theWebView
{
    return [super webViewDidStartLoad:theWebView];
}

- (void) webView:(UIWebView*)theWebView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    return [super webView:theWebView didFailLoadWithError:error];
}

- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView*)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    return [super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType];
}

*/
```

And, at last, before the line

```
  return [super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType];
```

insert this:

```
NSString* path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",request];

if([path hasPrefix:@"mailto"]==NO) {

    NSRange range = [path rangeOfString:@"/" options:NSBackwardsSearch];

    NSString* fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",[path substringFromIndex:range.location + 1]];


    [[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker set:kGAIScreenName
                                       value:fileName];

    [[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker
     send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] build]];


}
```

And that's all. Now you can follow your app, and even the insided pages handled by cordova.

I have to give the credits to my brother and the people of http://blog.fltlab.net/2012/04/10/phonegap-and-googleanalytics/ who gave me the hints.

UPDATE: after updating to Xcode 5.1, Cordova 3.4 (I was on 2.9) , I had to remake my cordova apps, and repeat all these steps; but I had to link another library (libsqlite3.dylib) at step 1.